# Edit Outlook email from Excel VBA

Tags: excel, excel-2010, outlook-2010, vba

I've got the below code to successfully use a pre-made Outlook template that is saved locally on my machine (fileName) and attach the Active Excel document into it, however there is some additional text that I'd like to add to the email template to save me the time to copy and paste it over. Is there anyway to add ADDITIONAL body text to the pre-made email template or if I can have my VBA code read the body text and then I can add to it by storing it in a temporary variable? It's a saved .msg file

```
Public Function GenerateEmail(sendTo As String, _
    sendCC As String, sendBCC As String, _
    subjectText As String, fileName As String)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItemFromTemplate(fileName)

    With OutMail
        .sendTo = sendToText
        .CC = sendCCText
        .BCC = sendBCCText
        .Subject = subjectText
        .Attachments.Add (Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName)
        .Display
    End With

    On Error GoTo 0

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With

End Function
```

Comment: the usual method to add to an existing variable `.body = "Add your Text here" & .body`  or `.Htmlbody = html markup & .Htmlbody`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to save down a template - you just draft a template (I typically use markers to substitute certain part of the body, depending on the recipient - like "Dear %Recipient%") and then "Save as" a .oft file. then run you code to sent the mails. I'd also use `.HTMLbody` to maintain the fomatting of the template so you'd put in

```
With OutMail
        .sendTo = sendToText
        .CC = sendCCText
        .BCC = sendBCCText
        .Subject = subjectText
        .HTMLbody= WorksheetFunction.Substitute(OutMail.HTMLbody, "%Recipient%", [Recipiants name here (this could be a stored string)])
        .Attachments.Add (Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName)
        .Display
End With
```

Comment: Wow this is exactly what I was looking for! I will test it out and get back to you! Thanks a ton! :)

Comment: @Maldred no problem :)

Comment: I tried running this and testing with the following `.HTMLbody = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(OutMail.HTMLbody, "%TESTNUM%", [98541])` gave me a compile error saying **"Unable to get the Substitute property of the WorksheetFunction class"** on that line. Do I need add any references to a library?

Comment: How do I add markers to an .oft file? I'm getting a compile error when I try to run the above code

Comment: @Maldred The squared brackets are just there to represent a placeholder - what you need to put, for your above example, is `.HTMLbody = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(OutMail.HTMLbody, "%TESTNUM%", "98541")`. To add markers, just go to wherever the .oft file is saved, open it and include whatever marker you need (these should be unique so as not to cause any issues when using the `.Substitute()` method - I've put % on either end of the marker but you could just as easily use "|", or "~".. or pretty much anything!)

Comment: I'm still receiving the same errors here, I'm using the exact line of code you're using here. `.HTMLbody = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(OutMail.HTMLbody, "%TESTNUM%", "98541")`

Comment: Do you have the Microsoft HTML Object Library referenced? (Tools > References.. )

Comment: So, I have the library referenced and I'm receiving an error stating `Unable to get the Substitute property of the WorksheetFunction class`

Comment: I'm running that code now (and have before) and not getting any errors.. immediately before `With OutMail` put in `If InStr(OutMail.HTMLbody, "%TESTNUM%") = 0 Then` followed by `MsgBox """%TESTNUM%""" & " isn't in your .oft file - that's your problem"`, follow by `Else`, followed by `MsgBox "Problem not clear"`, followed by `End If`
`

Comment: Hey Jeremy, I actually ended up using a different method... [Check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46918314/excel-range-added-to-email-template/46918315?noredirect=1#comment80784098_46918315)! I think you might like it too :)

Answer (score 0):

Just add a .body to the email text such as below

```
 With OutMail
        .sendTo = sendToText
        .CC = sendCCText
        .BCC = sendBCCText
        .Subject = subjectText
        .body = "Add your Text here"
        .Attachments.Add (Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName)
        .Display
End With
```

Comment: If I add this, the body that's on my template is over written by what i type in the OutMail.Body; I need a way I can read what's already on the template and add to it

Comment: How is the template created? (i.e. text or an image)

Comment: The email is a .msg file; basically what I did was when I created a new email I used "Save As" and saved it to a folder. So this code above is using one of 10 different saved emails that I've pre-made and will select which on to use based on other variables in play. Once it selects an email, it will attach the active worksheet and add everything except a body (which is in the saved file). All I want to do is add more text to the pre-existing body text