# Excel Range added to Email Template

Tags: vba, excel

Give the below function, I'd like to have the variable `%TABLE_HERE%` replaced with a table generated from the range of the Excel Spreadsheet that is also attached to the email.

```
Public Function GenerateEmail(fileName As String, tbleRange As Range)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItemFromTemplate(fileName)

    With OutMail
        .HTMLbody = Replace(OutMail.HTMLbody, "%TABLE_HERE%", RangetoHTML(tbleRange))
        .Attachments.Add (Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName)
        .Display
    End With

    On Error GoTo 0

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With

End Function
```

I did a bit of research and came across a great function that will do all this for you and wanted to share it with everyone here! Please refer to my answer below

Comment: Did you get it to work with a chart the way you wanted to?

Comment: I did, it works great too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
' Changed by Ron de Bruin 28-Oct-2006
' Working in Office 2000-2016
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
    rng.copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         fileName:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.readall
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")

    'Close TempWB
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

    'Delete the htm file we used in this function
    Kill TempFile

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```

[Website I got it from here...](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail2.htm)

Comment: I've used that exact function for years, I just have never tried it with a chart.