# Modify HTMLBody of Outlook Email, based on Template, from Excel

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am trying to modify the HTML body of an Outlook email, based on a template, from Excel VBA.

My code is:

```
Sub Email_Button()

Dim OutApp As Outlook.Application
Dim OutMail As Outlook.MailItem
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItemFromTemplate("S:\some\path\to\file\Email.oft")

With OutMail
    .Importance = olImportanceHigh
    .Subject = "Subject " & Date
    .Attachments.Add Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName
    .HTMLBody = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(OutMail.HTMLBody, "%target%", "replacement")
    .Display
End With

' *** TIDY UP ***
Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

The question is very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46733209/edit-outlook-email-from-excel-vba).

I get

> Run Time Error 287. Application-defined or object-defined error

on the .HTMLBody modification line.

If I remove this line the email is displayed for the user to check before hitting send.

I have referenced the Microsoft Outlook 15 Object Library.

I added:

```
With OutMail
    .bodyFormat = olFormatHTML
```

But got the same error on the Substitute line so I changed the substitute to:

```
.HTMLBody = "<HTML><BODY>Some HTML text here</BODY></HTML>"
```

And the body of the email was updated.

So the error is only present when trying to use substitute or its to do with the oft.

It looks like from the debugger that there is no HTML body:

[image]

I have confirmed that body type is set to HTML both programmatically:

[image]

and by opening the oft message and checking:

[image]

Comment: Why would you try a worksheet function to do the replacements when VBA has a built-in method to do so? `OutMail.HTMLBody = Replace(OutMail.HTMLBody, "String to find", "Replacement string")`

Comment: @RyszardJędraszyk that however doesn't address the question.

Comment: If its an Outlook Security error (which I think it might be) is there a way to store the HTML body as a file, modify it separately then add it to the body?

Comment: Is `OutMail` an HTML-formatted mail?

Comment: @TimWilliams yes.

Comment: This works for me - Win10/Office365

Comment: @TimWilliams I'm thinking security issue - there are some restrictions in place.

Comment: If you've properly identified the line where the error occurs, then the only place that that can cause the problem is that you don't have an HTML-formatted email, causing `.HTMLBody` to be nothing when you use it. (Unless, of course, somehow `WorksheetFunction.Substitute` isn't available.) You can test this by assigning `.HTMLBody` to a variable first, and then using that variable in the call to `Substitute`. Set a breakpoint at the variable assignment and step through the code.

Comment: Check the value of `OutMail.BodyFormat` against the `OlBodyFormat` enumeration [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.olbodyformat)

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the issue can be related to the `Substitute` method, so I'd suggest running the following code to make sure everything works correctly:

```
Sub CreateHTMLMail()  
 Dim OutApp As Outlook.Application
 Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
 'Creates a new email item and modifies its properties.  
 Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem  
 'Create email item  
 Set objMail = OutApp.CreateItemFromTemplate("S:\some\path\to\file\Email.oft")
 With objMail  
 'Set body format to HTML  
 .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML  
 .HTMLBody = "<HTML><BODY>Enter the message text here. </BODY></HTML>"  
 .Display  
 End With  
End Sub
```

Another aspect is Outlook security prompts. Read more about that in the ["A program is trying to send an e-mail message on your behalf" warning in Outlook](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3189806/a-program-is-trying-to-send-an-e-mail-message-on-your-behalf-warning-i) article.

Answer (score 0):

The most probable cause is Outlook Security.

For security purposes, the HTMLBody, HTMLEditor, Body and WordEditor properties all are subject to address-information security prompts because the body of a message often contains the sender's or other people's e-mail addresses.

You can find the security configurations in HKCU\Software\Policies\Microsoft\office\16.0\outlook\security\
(change 16.0 to your office version)

There are two values that you can check, promptoomaddressbookaccess and promptoomaddressinformationaccess

Change them to 2 (or ask your system administrator), restart Outlook and try again.

More info https://support.microsoft.com/en-za/help/926512/information-for-administrators-about-e-mail-security-settings-in-outlo